# 3D modeling software for a home improvement project?

Tags: 3d-modeling

I would like to add an additional bedroom and a sun-room to my house. I am wondering whether there is any 3D modeling software that is easy to use and would allow me to model a part of my current house. Then allow me to model my expansions so that I can have a rough idea of materials and maybe a blueprint or such I can take to the city for approval.

Right now I'm considering Google Sketch-Up though that is going to be a tedious process... drawing out every 4 by 4 and so on...

I've never done a home improvement project, at least not one of this scale before. I would also appreciate any advice on the easiest way to run and have this project approved by the city.

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

if you do not need the technical drawings as output, you can try [Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp). As I know it is primarily focused on interior and furniture, but could help you.

[image]

About the approval, I am not sure how about your country, but in Czech Republic you need technical drawings made by some certified people to ensure the quality of the construction etc. (I have only basic knowledge about this).

Other possible solution is (as you mentioned) Google Sketchup or maybe also [Anim8or](http://www.anim8or.com) which has some useful scripts [here](http://www.anim8or.com/scripts/index.html) and [these](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/w.watson3/main/parameteric.html) especially for buildings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/)  it's easy to use and renders pretty professional looking 3-d models. You can view what other people have created to get some good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

[Autodesk Revit](http://www.autodesk.com/products/revit-family/features/software-for-bim/all/gallery-view) is amazing, it creates floor plans, rendered pictures, and is industry-standard. It is extremely expensive, but if you are in some sort of school or university you can get a free 3 year license.